# How to find the View of a Button in its Click EventHandler

Tags: android, view, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have a Button 'Remove' on a `View`, lets call it `UserInputView`. `UserInputView` is added to a `Layout` by user input. Now, the user may have typed something wrong, and wants to press the Remove-button I've created, to remove this particular `UserInputView`.

I've added an `EventHandler` for the `Click`-event of the Remove-button. Now I need to find what View-object this particular Button belongs to so I can call `_myLayout.RemoveView(theViewICantFind)`. How do I find this View-object? I can't seem find it by any properties of the Button in question.

Or perhaps, is it another clever way of removing the `UserInputView` from the Layout that I don't know about?

Thanks folks!

Comment: Have you tried using `getParent()` to find the containing view? If it's nested in more than one `ViewGroup`, it may take a few chained calls.

Comment: Ahh, okay - there you go. I misunderstood when I saw that Parent.Parent.Parent (etc. etc.) was a TableLayout when traversing my Button-object, not thinking this is actually the View I was looking for. Thanks dude!

Comment: Add it as an answer if you want the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `EventHandler`, there is a sender `object`. That is the actual `View` object.

I suppose you could remove it like this in the `Click` handler:

```
public void MyButtonHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    _myLayout.RemoveView(button);
}
```

If you want to remove the view the `Button` belongs to, you can just get it by calling `button.Parent`.